# asp.net how to map a navigation property from context by its id

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, mapping, automapper

I have two classes, one of which is data transfer object, and the other is database object.
DBO:

```
public class FinancialOperationDTO
{
    public double Sum { get; set; }
    public DateTime OperationDate { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

DB:

```
public class FinancialOperation
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public double Sum { get; set; }
    public DateTime OperationDate { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; } // navigation property
}
```

How can I create a db object "category" navigation property from a dbo object categoryname property? Not even create, but to set it from existing ones by it's name. I need smth like

```
CreateMap<FinancialOperationDTO, FinancialOperation>()
      .ForMember(dest =>
       dest.Category,
       opt => opt.MapFrom(src => "where category name == context.Categories.CategoryName")); //code in quotes is what I'm expecting
```

p.s: category class

```
public class Category
{
        public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is the CategoryName guaranteed to be a unique identifier for the category table?

Comment: Not yet, but I will add this